# Mysql Installation Problems with 18.04

Tags: apt, server, software-installation, mysql, 18.04

I installed a fresh copy of 18.04 am installing all the packages that are required. When installing `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` I receive the following error

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried the `purge, autoremove, autoclean, dist-upgrade` routine but it does not work for me.

How do I fix this problem, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by going to Oracles mysql documentation on [MySQL APT Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install) which was a huge help, following all the instructions on the page allowed me to install `mysql` successfully.

What I did:

1. Download the `mysql-apt-conf` tool from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/
2. Install the package using `sudo dpkg -i /PATH/version-specific-package-name.deb`
3. When installing select `MySQL Server & Cluster` to whatever you want by pressing enter and selecting one of `mysql-5.7` or `mysql-8.0` then go to `Ok` and press enter
4. Then `sudo apt-get update`(this step is required only for Ubuntu 17.10 or below)
5. Run `sudo apt install mysql-server`
6. After the main packages are installed run `mysql_secure_installation`, this will configure the password and other security stuff for mysql

**Update**

If anyone ran or had to run mysql_secure_installation with`sudo`, please note that you might not be able to login into mysql unless you use sudo. When this happens login to mysql console created a new user for mysql then flush all privileges. Check this question right here [Connect to mysql server without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239970/connect-to-mysql-server-without-sudo)

Comment: With that instruction I have now the error message for  mysql-community-server and  mysql-server
Really weird.
So the same error for a different package.

Comment: Can you please put the error message here.

Comment: Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-03-17 20:39:21 CET; 12ms ago
  Process: 12066 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: by now I have installed, removed, deleted folders, installed again, that I cannot say, what the real status quo is by now except that it is still not running.