# Installing MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 18.10 failing

Tags: mysql

I have installed `mysql-apt-config` package from [mysql-apt-config](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=487007) the package installed is `mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb`.

While following solution from [Mysql Installation problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029162/mysql-installation-problems-with-18-04) when I run command `sudo apt install mysql-server` I am receiving this response

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
  mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
  mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.0 MB/20.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 159 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

System is trying to install `mysql-server-5.7` & `mysql-client-5.7` instead of MySQL 8.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic)

Answer (score 0):

Try `aptitude show mysql-server` (presuming third-party repositories been configured and `apt-get update` run).
In my similar case with Nginx (and now with MySQL installed from .deb), I noticed the correct new version at the top of output, while "Provided by" (much like as "to be installed", as seems to me) packages still showed much older version. Continuing with installation, I received the newest version I was looking for.
I'm, unfortunately, unable to check this on clean OS now..